# Attempting to have scene load with camera position the same as it left off

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically, think Mario here, I have a world map. A player enters a level, then when the player returns to the Map, I want it to load the camera position the player last left off on. I am having trouble doing this and it keeps resetting back to the original camera position.

Here is what I've tried so far:

I have a WorldManager class with the following code:

```
    private void Start()
{
    highestLevelUnlocked = PlayerPrefsManager.GetHighestLevelUnlocked();
    if (highestLevelUnlocked > 0)
    {
        rectTransform.offsetMin = new Vector2(PlayerPrefsManager.GetLastLevelViewedLeft(), rectTransform.offsetMin.x);
        rectTransform.offsetMax = new Vector2(PlayerPrefsManager.GetLastLevelViewedRight(), rectTransform.offsetMax.x);
    }
    else
    {
        rectTransform.offsetMin = new Vector2(0, 0);
        rectTransform.offsetMax = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }
}

// Sets the camera coordinates.
public void SetCameraCoordinates()
{
    PlayerPrefsManager.SetLastLevelViewed(Mathf.RoundToInt(rectTransform.offsetMin.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(rectTransform.offsetMax.x));
}
```

I'm sure i'm doing something completely wrong but I can't figure it out and was hoping for some insight.

PlayerPrefsManager is static and holds onto player data between scenes.

Thank you!

Edit : I'm using a Scroll View for the player to scroll across the map with mouse/thumbs.

Comment: How do your `SetLastLevelViewed`, `GetLastLevelViewedLeft` and `GetLastLevelViewedRight` look like? I'ld also recommend not to use a static class but rather a [ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html)

Comment: Thanks for this! I haven't looked into ScriptableObject. I will read up on this now!

Comment: [This tutorial](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects) is actually a better start point than the docs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for anyone who looked at this. I was able to solve the problem by using the following:

```
    private void Start()
{
    lastLevelViewed = PlayerPrefsManager.GetLastLevelViewed();
    if(lastLevelViewed > 0)
    {
        scrollRect.horizontalScrollbar.value = PlayerPrefsManager.GetLastLevelViewed();
    }
    else
    {
        scrollRect.horizontalScrollbar.value = 0;
    }
}

// Sets the camera coordinates.
public void SetCameraCoordinates()
{
    PlayerPrefsManager.SetLastLevelViewed(scrollRect.horizontalScrollbar.value);
}
```